# xmalloc: cannot allocate 16 bytes copying mysql database from 1 remote to another

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I have 2 remote servers behind bastion servers, and I am trying to clone 1 MySQL database to another. I have a script on one bastion server sending data to another script on the other bastion server, and it appears to be running out of memory. The database is about 2.7G and these servers have 2G RAM. It appears that it is loading the entire database into memory, but I'm not sure why. Is there something in these scripts that is loading the entire db into memory? Here are the scripts:

**migrateToRemote.sh** (on bastion 1)

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ubuntu@<ipaddress> "mysqldump -h <db host> -u <db user> -p<db password> <orig db name>" | ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ubuntu@<ipaddress> "/home/ubuntu/forwardDbMigration.sh"
```

**forwardDbMigration.sh** (on bastion 2)

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ubuntu@<ip address> "mysql -h <db host> -u <db user> -p<db password> <new db name>" < $(< /dev/stdin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysql ... < $(< /dev/stdin)

I don't think this does what you think it does. The `$( )` substitution in bash is not just I/O redirection. It runs a command.

Your usage reads /dev/stdin, and then tries to execute that content as a command. That's probably where it ran out of memory, trying to form a command that is 2.7GB long.

Here's a demo of what I mean:

```
echo date | $(</dev/stdin)
Tue Nov 19 07:34:14 PST 2019
```

This is reading the string "date" from /dev/stdin and then executing the command `date`. The output is not the string "date" — it's the result of executing `date`, because it's enclosed in `$( )`.

Another demo:

```
echo "hello world" | $(</dev/stdin)
-bash: hello: command not found
```

See? It's trying to *execute* "hello world" as a command after reading it from stdin.

You don't want to execute the content of your mysqldump, it is not a series of shell commands. You just want to pass that content as the input to `mysql`.

If you want `forwardDbMigration.sh` to pass its stdin to `mysql`, I think you only need to do this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ubuntu@<ip address> "mysql -h <db host> -u <db user> -p<db password> <new db name>"
```

I'm also not sure why your `forwardDbMigration.sh` contains an ssh command at all, because you are already ssh'ing to the bastion host to run it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense now. The forwardDbMigration.sh contains an ssh command because it is just a bastion and not the server that runs the mysql command. The script runs, and it seems to take a couple minutes.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. The bastion host ssh's to another host where it runs mysql to import data to MySQL Server running on a third host. :-)

Comment: Well, I have 2 AWS RDS instances each in their own private VPC, which each has its own bastion server. Each VPC also has a service server. I could just have the bastion servers run the mysql commands, but they are not able to install mysql utilities since they do not have access to the internet, they are basically just relay servers. It's a bit of a ratsnest.